# Setting On windows' High Performance power plan using C++ winAPI

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Ive written a code trying to activate the windows' high perfomance power plan through the winAPI in c++. It seems to work well for all the power plans (in my terminal they are called Balanced, Power saver and Dell) excepting for the one im interested in, the high performance plan! I would like the code to go over through  all the power plans and when finding the high performance one just set it on and then quit. Ill put my code underneath in case anybody can help me. thanks in advance!

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <powrprof.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
#include <ntstatus.h>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib, "powrprof.lib")

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char **argv) {


//////////////////  SET ACTIVE HIGH PERFORMANCE PLAN  ///////////////////


//Variables
UCHAR displayBuffer[64] = " ";
DWORD displayBufferSize = sizeof(displayBuffer);
GUID buffer;
DWORD bufferSize = sizeof(buffer);

//Go throught the machine's power plans and activate the high performance one
for(int index = 0; ; index++)
{

    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == PowerEnumerate(NULL,NULL,&GUID_VIDEO_SUBGROUP,ACCESS_SCHEME,index,(UCHAR*)&buffer,&bufferSize) )
    {
        if (ERROR_SUCCESS == PowerReadFriendlyName(NULL,&buffer,&NO_SUBGROUP_GUID,NULL,displayBuffer,&displayBufferSize) )
        {
            wprintf(L"%s\n", (wchar_t*)displayBuffer);


            if( 0 == wcscmp ( (wchar_t*)displayBuffer, L"High Performance" ) )
            {
                cout << "High Performance Plan Found!\n";
                if (ERROR_SUCCESS == PowerSetActiveScheme(NULL,&buffer) )
                {
                cout << "* Setting Active High Performance Power Plan *";
                //std::cin.get(); //pause
                break;
                }

            }
        }

    }
    else break;
}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: Try to call GetLastError() just after PowerSetActiveScheme and share the result

Comment: Thanks. The only error comes when comparing in if( 0 == wcscmp ( (wchar_t*)displayBuffer, L"High Performance" ) ) and the value of LastError is 3435973836 which I have no idea what it means :). After PowerSetActiveScheme I doesnt get any error because programm never goes into that if clause. The script doesnt find the high perf. plan so it never goes to run the PowerSetActiveScheme..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done a bit easier:

```
PowerSetActiveScheme(0, &GUID_MIN_POWER_SAVINGS);
```

Comment: It worked! thanks Simon Richter! 

btw, where can I check that &GUID_MIN_POWER_SAVINGS means High Perf Plan?

Comment: found. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554353(v=vs.85).aspx    thanks again, you changed my 50 code lines for just 1 :)